# Bulk Delete Custom Entities (Not Entity Types)

Tags: 7, entities, batch-operations

I have a 5000+ entries for custom Entities created by the RedHen module (https://drupal.org/project/redhen). I want to wipe them completely from the system (they are all test entries). How can I do this quickly? I tried to get Views Bulk Operations and the Delete All modules but neither seem to be picking up the custom entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  delete multiple entities using below API functions

[entity_load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/entity_load/7)

> Load entities from the database.
>
> The entities are stored in a static memory cache, and will not require
>   database access if loaded again during the same page request.
>
> $entity_type: The entity type to load, e.g. node or user.
>
> $ids: An array of entity IDs, or FALSE to load all entities.

[entity_delete_multiple](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_delete_multiple/7)

> Permanently delete multiple entities.

For Example to delete all node entities

```
<?php
  $results = entity_load('node');
  $entity_ids = array_keys($results);
  entity_delete_multiple('node', $entity_ids);
  ?>
```

Comment: Yes this looks right, but I'm confused on proper usages of this. Ideally i just want to run this once or twice. Would I add this to my custom module and have it hook and run with update.php?

Comment: How many Entity Types do you have ?

Comment: Actually I was able to put this in a preprocess function on a specific page I created and it worked! I had to separate it out in chunks though, I had over 100,000 entities in the DB. So it worked! Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This simple module might help you:
https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_bulk_delete